# HTML Video does not occupy 100% width

Tags: css, html, html5-video

I cant get the `video` to scale to 100% of the `width` of the `.video` container. Something like [this](https://www.wealthfront.com/) but only such that the video occupies a `max-height` of `50vh`.

Is it possible to do that? If yes, could you please tell me how?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.container .video {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
}
.container .video video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="video">
    <video muted autoplay loop>
      <source src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dlm2jcfic/video/upload/v1465860427/343732582_johq2x.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Videos are commonly encoded with the AR (Aspect Ratio) of 16:9 (16 width to it's 9 height).

- Set video element to:

  ```
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
  ```
- That should make it be able to stretch at it's maximum length
- Then apply this to the container:

  ```
      position: relative;
      height: 0;
      width: 100%;
      padding-bottom:56.25%;
  ```
- This will collapse itself, and expand at the same time. The strange`padding-bottom` value will act like ceran wrap over a plate of food. This combo of styles is responsive and pretty well **[established](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php)**.

#### SNIPPET

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.container .video {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom:56.25%;
}
.container .video video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="video">
    <video muted autoplay loop>
      <source src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dlm2jcfic/video/upload/v1465860427/343732582_johq2x.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Erase the `height: 50vh;` from `.container .video video`:
(Insisting on that could only distort the proportions - makes no sense)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.container .video {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
}
.container .video video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="video">
    <video muted autoplay loop>
      <source src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dlm2jcfic/video/upload/v1465860427/343732582_johq2x.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can set `html,body` to `height:100%` and `video` to  `height:50%` and `width:100%`

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%
}
.container video {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <video muted autoplay loop>
    <source src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dlm2jcfic/video/upload/v1465860427/343732582_johq2x.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
<div class="content">


  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla accumsan nisi eget semper consequat. Pellentesque sed vulputate enim. Aenean condimentum dolor eu porttitor feugiat. Sed nec arcu maximus nulla scelerisque hendrerit ac in turpis. Lorem ipsum
  dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vitae semper odio. Aliquam consequat porttitor sapien, at luctus diam euismod eget. Vestibulum eleifend fringilla massa, nec bibendum nisl congue eu. Nulla mattis mi eu neque efficitur luctus. Praesent
  vulputate, orci ornare consectetur consequat, eros ante ultrices urna, quis dictum urna justo at quam.
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `object-fit` property of CSS with value `cover` along with `width:100%;`. 
This property can take five values: `object-fit: contain | cover | fill | none | scale-down;` Use whichever suits you the best.
This property sets how the content of a replaced element, such as an <img> or <video>, should be resized to fit its container.
For more details visit this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the video has a fixed aspect ratio. The video won't get any wider because it's not tall enough. You'll have to increase the height a bit, or get rid of the height property altogether as I've done [here](https://jsfiddle.net/chriseckenrode/7gxx1w48/1/)

```
.container .video video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```